# Find the characteristic function of $X$ given all moments of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a discrete random variable whose moments are given by $E(X^k) = p$, $k = 1, 2, ... $, where $0 < p < 1$, find the characteristic function of $X$.

**Attempt:**

Since X has all of its moments, then X is infinitely differentiable at the origin. Therefore I thought about taylor expanding the characteristic function $\varphi_X$ as

$$ \varphi_X(t) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \varphi_X^{(n)}(0)\frac{t^n}{n!}= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}p\frac{i^nt^n}{n!} = pe^{it}$$

I'm not too far off from the correct solution because this answer is close to the official answer:

**Official Answer:**

$$ (1 - p) + pe^{it} $$

Comment: Your expansion is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\varphi_X(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(itX)^k}{k!}\right]=1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{p(it)^k}{k!}=1-p+pe^{it}$

Comment: Would you mind explaining where that $-p$ comes from?

Comment: @Victor S. The final sum is the Taylor series of the exponent multiplied by $p$, but it is missing the first term.